# Timeout occurs in browser when waiting for report to be generated, how to force it to wait?

Tags: browser, reporting-services, timeout

Basically our client has been punishing our reports with a serious amount of records which has resulted in the below error.  Essentially the query isn't good enough and despite generating the report, it takes about 25minutes, during which time the below image is displayed to the client due to timeout.  I have been trying to optimize the query but frankly it is still taking far too long at 10minutes and I feel the same issue will arise as the client is taking about using even larger datasets.

Is there anyway I can make sure the below error doesn't occur?  If I generate the report using visual studio reporting services, it may take 10-15minutes but at least the report is generated, how can I force the browser to wait until the report is generated?

The client is putting a rush on this so at least with this solution they will get what they need.

[image: timeout error displayed]

I've changed it to a stored procedure and all the extra outer joins were to replace a function call which I thought may have been the cause of the slowdown.  An additional index was added in a hope to speed things up but no luck so far.

SQL Profiler shows an index seek which takes a hell of a lot of time but I can't see how to improve this.

This is the execution plan for the original query that was run, changes have resulted in significant differences we're still trying to figure out.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21484692/showplan.SQLPlan

Here is the SQL:

```
USE [Apollo_Interface_Staging]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spRptGMPP_UploadResults]    Script Date: 01/27/2012 11:09:13 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spRptGMPP_UploadResults]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here 
@StartDate DATETIME,
@EndDate DATETIME,
@UploadStatus VARCHAR(15)

AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @TrueEndDate DATETIME
SELECT @TrueEndDate = (select DATEADD(ms,-3,DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,@EndDate), 1)))

SELECT
VIN1
,TR_DATE
,CASE WHEN REC_STAT = 'A' THEN 'Add' WHEN REC_STAT = 'D' THEN 'Delete' WHEN REC_STAT = 'C' THEN 'Change' ELSE REC_STAT END as REC_STAT
, FRAN_CDE
, WARR_ODD
, WARR_MTH
, cast(rds_fee as money)/100  * CASE WHEN REC_STAT = 'D' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END as Fee
,PROV

,ROUND((gst.Percentage)/100 * cast(rds_fee as money)/100 * CASE WHEN REC_STAT = 'D' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END,2) as GST
,CASE WHEN prov NOT IN ('ON','BC') THEN
    ROUND((hst.Percentage)/100 * cast(rds_fee as money)/100 *CASE WHEN REC_STAT = 'D' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END,2) 
    ELSE 0
    END as HST
,CASE WHEN prov = 'ON' THEN
    ROUND((hst.Percentage)/100 * cast(rds_fee as money)/100 *CASE WHEN REC_STAT = 'D' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END,2) 
    ELSE 0
    END as HST_ON
,CASE WHEN prov = 'BC' THEN
    ROUND((hst.Percentage)/100 * cast(rds_fee as money)/100 *CASE WHEN REC_STAT = 'D' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END,2) 
    ELSE 0
    END as HST_BC
,ROUND((hst.Percentage)/100 * cast(rds_fee as money)/100 *CASE WHEN REC_STAT = 'D' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END,2) as HST
,ROUND((1 + (gst.Percentage)/100) 
                    * (qst.Percentage)/100 * cast(rds_fee as money)/100, 2) *CASE WHEN REC_STAT = 'D' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END as QST
,_UploadStatus as UploadStatus
,CAST(YEAR(_UploadDate) as varchar)+ '/' + RIGHT('0' + cast(MONTH(_UploadDate)as varchar) ,2)+ '/' + RIGHT('0' + DAY(_UploadDate),2) as UploadDate
,_UploadDescription as UploadDescription
,'' as VehicleMake--,Apollo.dbo.GetGMManufacturerFromVIN(VIN1) AS VehicleMake
,'' as VehicleYear--,Apollo.dbo.GetVehYear(VIN1) AS VehicleYear
,ID
,ISNULL(mem.MembershipID,'') as MembershipID
,ISNULL(mem.MembershipTermID,'') as MembershipTermID
,ISNULL(p.Name,'') as [Plan]
,CASE mem.ActionTaken
     WHEN 0 THEN 'None'
     WHEN 1 THEN 'Upgraded'
     WHEN 2 THEN 'Reverse Upgrade'
     WHEN 3 THEN 'Created'
     WHEN 4 THEN 'Cancelled'
     WHEN 5 THEN 'Status Changed'
     WHEN 6 THEN 'Static Update'
     ELSE ''
 END as Action
,ISNULL((SELECT SUM(mtd.Amount) FROM Apollo.dbo.MemberTransactionDetail mtd WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE mtd.MemberTransactionID = mem.TransactionID),0) as TransactionAmount
,ISNULL((select SUM(pe.InitialValue) from apollo_drm..[transaction] trx WITH(NOLOCK) inner join apollo_drm..paymentelement pe WITH(NOLOCK) ON pe.transactionid = trx.transactionid where trx.externalref = mem.TransactionID AND trx.ExternalRef > 0),0) as DRMTransactionAmount
,gm.STAMP as DateTimeStamp
FROM
Apollo_Interface_Staging.dbo.gmpp_archive gm WITH(NOLOCK)  
LEFT OUTER JOIN Apollo_Interface_Staging.dbo.GMPP_Effected_Memberships mem WITH(NOLOCK) ON mem.GMPP_ImportID = gm.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Apollo..MembershipTerm mt WITH(NOLOCK) ON mt.MembershipTermID = mem.MembershipTermID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Apollo..[PlanVersion] pv WITH(NOLOCK) ON pv.PlanVersionID = mt.PlanVersionID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Apollo..[Plan] p WITH(NOLOCK) ON p.PlanID = pv.PlanID

LEFT OUTER JOIN APollo..PRovinceOrSTateTax gst WITH(NOLOCK) ON gst.PRovinceOrStateTaxID = (
    SELECT TOP 1 tmp.PRovinceOrStateTaxID 
   FROM   Apollo.dbo.ProvinceOrStateTax tmp 
   WHERE  tmp.TaxTypeProgKey = 'GST' 
              AND tmp.ProvinceOrStateProgKey = prov
              AND tmp.StartDate <= GETDATE()
   ORDER BY
          tmp.StartDate DESC
)                               
LEFT OUTER JOIN APollo..PRovinceOrSTateTax hst WITH(NOLOCK) ON hst.PRovinceOrStateTaxID = (
    SELECT TOP 1 tmp.PRovinceOrStateTaxID 
   FROM   Apollo.dbo.ProvinceOrStateTax tmp 
   WHERE  tmp.TaxTypeProgKey = 'HST' 
              AND tmp.ProvinceOrStateProgKey = prov
              AND tmp.StartDate <= GETDATE()
   ORDER BY
          tmp.StartDate DESC
)                                                                                             
LEFT OUTER JOIN APollo..PRovinceOrSTateTax qst WITH(NOLOCK) ON qst.PRovinceOrStateTaxID = (
    SELECT TOP 1 tmp.PRovinceOrStateTaxID 
   FROM   Apollo.dbo.ProvinceOrStateTax tmp 
   WHERE  tmp.TaxTypeProgKey = 'QST' 
              AND tmp.ProvinceOrStateProgKey = prov
              AND tmp.StartDate <= GETDATE()
   ORDER BY
          tmp.StartDate DESC
)       

WHERE
STAMP BETWEEN @StartDate AND @TrueEndDate
AND 
(
    @UploadStatus = 'ALL' 
        OR 
    _UploadStatus = @UploadStatus
)
END
```

In terms of attempted resolution I tried the parameter sniffing route, by putting the dates directly into the stored procedure instead of allowing the user to select them, it chopped off around 3 minutes, but this is obviously not really a solution for us and even then it's still desperately slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waiting for a report should never take this long.
Is it possible that you are doing something incorrectly or without proper indexing.
Can you post your SQL that accesses the dataset?

The other option you have is to create an RS subscription that exports the report out to pdf format and throws it on a client share directory every say 30 minutes.  That way the client doesnt even have to wait for the report - they can expect the report to be ready in the network share folder.  You can adjust the time directly in reporting services so that you can generate this report every say 10 minutes / 20 minutes / etc.

Comment: Added the SQL etc for more information.  I suppose exporting reports run from here is an option, one I have considered too but thought this might be a way around things with regard to handling the browser time out.  Is it not a possibility?

Comment: @shicky we may be able to fix some of that sql that is a lot of code.  Can you post the execution plan for some of this.  I think the cost is due to the BETWEEN and the OR condition.

Comment: Put a link up for the execution plan for the original query.  Tried going down the route of parameter sniffing without much luck.  Changes in terms of me switching to a stored procedure not using parameters have completely changed the execution plan which is interesting.  What do you think is wrong with that condition?  I'm not sure what alternative there would be?

Now investigating whether the grouping in SSRS may be the issue

Comment: @schicky outside of reporting services when you run that query how long does it take?

Comment: It's acting up now for some reason but previously in SQL studio we could execute the original query in around 1min 48 which went down to 30seconds but due to caching.  The attempt to generate the report in SSRS took 25minutes.

Comment: I've got it down a good 5minutes by removing the grouping in the report and using my stored proc with pre-defined values - unfortunately these aren't really potential solutions

Comment: shicky to be honest there isnt too much you can do, you have a LOT of ISNULL, CASE, and NOT IN in your queries, and I don't know your business logic so I cannot recommend removing them if you really need them.  When I see a lot of ISNULL's like that and replacing empty strings with values I always wonder why the dba or developer didnt see allow nulls to false for a column.  Too many columns that allow nulls cause more headache then its worth.  You have to really think about how to design columns when you allow for nulls.  Do you really want a null or not..but again I cannot help with that.

Comment: That's no problem JonH, thank you for taking the time to look at my question, it is much appreciated.  I'll upvote just because you gave me several ideas which allowed things to progress further but as you said a total resolution seems difficult in the circumstances